# Python, Matching uneven length scraped lists

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Please prepare for a long read.  I am at a standstill and don't know where to look at for an answer / what else to try.  Needless to say I am kinda new to programming.  Been hacking away at this project for the past couple of weeks.

**PROBLEM**

I got this table, 25 lines, 2 columns.  Each line is structured like:

**Needed event**

```
<td align=center>19/11/11<br>12:01:21 AM</td>
<td align=center><font color=#006633><a href=profiles.php?XID=1><font color=#006633>player1</font></a> hospitalized <a href=profiles.php?XID=2><font color=#006633>player2</font></a></font></td>
```

**NOT Needed event 
CASE A**

```
<td align="center">19/11/11<br />12:58:03 AM</td>
<td align="center"><font color="#AA0000">Someone hospitalized <a href=profiles.php?XID=1><font color="#AA0000">player1</font></a></font></td>
```

**NOT Needed event 
CASE B**

```
<td align="center">19/11/11<br />12:58:03 AM</td>
<td align=center><font color=#006633><a href=profiles.php?XID=3><font color=#006633>player3</font></a> attacked <a href=profiles.php?XID=1><font color=#006633>player1</font></a> and lost </font></td>
```

I have used regex to scrape the needed data.  My problem is that the 2 lists are not evently matched.  Date and time don't always match to the exact event.

---

**1st ATTEMPT at solving problem**

```
import mechanize  
import re

htmlA1 = br.response().read()

patAttackDate = re.compile('<td align=center>(\d+/\d+/\d+)<br>(\d+:\d+:\d+ \w+)')
patAttackName = re.compile('<font color=#006633>(\w+)</font></a> hospitalized ')
searchAttackDate = re.findall(patAttackDate, htmlA1)
searchAttackName = re.findall(patAttackName, htmlA1)

pairs = zip(searchAttackDate, searchAttackName)

for i in pairs:
print (i)
```

But that gets me a `wrong time - correct event` type of list.

for example:

```
(('19/11/11', '9:47:51 PM'), 'user1') <- mismatch 
(('19/11/11', '8:21:18 PM'), 'user1') <- mismatch
(('19/11/11', '7:33:00 PM'), 'user1') <- As a consequence of the below, the rest upwards are mismatched 
(('19/11/11', '7:32:38 PM'), 'user2') <- NOT a match, case B
(('19/11/11', '7:32:22 PM'), 'user2') <- match ok
(('19/11/11', '7:26:53 PM'), 'user2') <- match ok
(('19/11/11', '7:25:24 PM'), 'user3') <- match ok
(('19/11/11', '7:24:22 PM'), 'user3') <- match ok
(('19/11/11', '7:23:25 PM'), 'user3') <- match ok
```

---

**2nd ATTEMPT at solving problem**

So thought to strip the `newline` from the whole page and scrape the table, but:

```
import mechanize
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

htmlA1 = br.response().read()

stripped = htmlA1.replace(">\n<","><") #Removed all '\n' from code

soup = BeautifulSoup(stripped)

table = soup.find('table', width='90%')
table2 = table.findNext('table', width='90%')
table3 = table2.findNext('table', width='90%') #this is the table I need to work with

patAttackDate = re.compile('<td align="center">(\d+/\d+/\d+)<br />(\d+:\d+:\d+ \w+)')
searchAttackDate = re.findall(patAttackDate, table3)
print searchAttackDate
```

this gives me an error:

```
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

What am I missing?

Bonus question:
Is there any way to account for XID being a dynamic variable but bypass it when using regex / beautifulsoup (or other scraping method)?  As the project 'grows' I might need to include the XID portion of code but don't want to match to it. (not sure if this is clear)

Thank you for your time

---

**EDIT 1**: Added list example
**EDIT 2**: Made code separation more visible
**EDIT 3**: Added sample code for a given solution that doesn't seem to work

```
Test = '''<table><tr><td>date</td></tr></table>'''
soupTest = BeautifulSoup(Test)
test2 = soupTest.find('table')
patTest = re.compile('<td>(.*)</td>')
searchTest = patTest.findall(test2.getText())
print test2 # gives: <table><tr><td>date</td></tr></table> 
print type(test2) # gives: <class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>
print searchTest #gives: []
```

**EDIT 4 - Solution**

```
import re
import mechanize
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

htmlA1 = br.response().read()
stripped = htmlA1.replace(">\n<","><") #stripped '\n' from html
soup = BeautifulSoup(stripped)

table = soup.find('table', width='90%')
table2 = table.findNext('table', width='90%')
table3 = table2.findNext('table', width='90%') #table I need to work with

print type(table3) # gives <class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>
strTable3 = str(table3) #convert table3 to string type so i can regex it

patFinal = re.compile(('(\d+/\d+/\d+)<br />(\d+:\d+:\d+ \w+)</td><td align="center">'
                      '<font color="#006633"><a href="profiles.php\?XID=(\d+)">'
                      '<font color="#006633">(\w+)</font></a> hospitalized <a'), re.IGNORECASE)
searchFinal = re.findall(patFinal, strTable3)

for i in searchFinal:
    print (i)
```

---

**Sample output**

```
('19/11/11', '1:08:07 AM', 'ID_user1', 'user1')
('19/11/11', '1:06:55 AM', 'ID_user1', 'user1')
('19/11/11', '1:05:46 AM', 'ID_user1', 'user1')
('19/11/11', '1:04:33 AM', 'ID_user1', 'user1')
('19/11/11', '1:03:32 AM', 'ID_user1', 'user1')
('19/11/11', '1:02:37 AM', 'ID_user1', 'user1')
('19/11/11', '1:00:43 AM', 'ID_user1', 'user1')
('19/11/11', '12:55:35 AM', 'ID_user2', 'user2')
```

**EDIT 5 - A much simpler solution (on 1st attempt - without Beautifulsoup)**

```
import re

reAttack = (r'<td\s+align=center>(\d+/\d+/\d+)<br>(\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\w+)</td>\s*'
            '<td.*?' #accounts for the '\n'
            '<font\s+color=#006633>(\w+)</font></a>\s+hospitalized\s+')

for m in re.finditer(reAttack, htmlA1):
    print 'date: %s; time: %s; player: %s' % (m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3))
```

**Sample Output**

```
date: 19/11/11; time: 1:08:07 AM; player: user1
date: 19/11/11; time: 1:06:55 AM; player: user1
date: 19/11/11; time: 1:05:46 AM; player: user1
date: 19/11/11; time: 1:04:33 AM; player: user1
date: 19/11/11; time: 1:03:32 AM; player: user1
date: 19/11/11; time: 1:02:37 AM; player: user1
date: 19/11/11; time: 1:00:43 AM; player: user1
date: 19/11/11; time: 12:55:35 AM; player: user2
```

Comment: No wonder you're having problems. You're using regular expressions on HTML.

Comment: could you clarfiy the rules for the needed cases? since I'm not sure using direct regex are the best way to solve this in python and besides I don't understand your exact date problem

Comment: I'm just waiting to see how many people ignore the fact that you are using BeautifulSoup and just post this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @alonisser, I have included an example of the ouput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
reAttack = r'<td\s+align=center>(\d+/\d+/\d+)<br>(\d+:\d+:\d+\s+\w+)</td>\s*<td.*?<font\s+color=#006633>(\w+)</font></a>\s+hospitalized\s+'

for m in re.finditer(reAttack, htmlA1):
  print 'date: %s; time: %s; player: %s' % (m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3))
```

**[live demo](http://ideone.com/aYhiO)**

Doing everything in one regex makes for a messier regex, but it's a lot easier than matching each TD separately and trying to sync them up afterward, as you're doing.  The `.*?` near the middle of the regex works on the assumption that all the elements are separated by newlines, as in your original examples.  If you can't assume that, you should replace the `.*?` with `(?:(?!/?td>).)*` to contain the match within the current TD element.

FYI, there were some inconsistencies in your sample data.  Some attribute values were quoted while most were not, and you had a mix of `<br>` and `<br />` tags.  I normalized everything for my demo, but if that's representative of your real data, you'll need a much more complicated regex.  Or you could switch to a pure DOM solution, which probably would have been easier in the first place. ;)

Comment: A much simpler solution.  Thanks.  BTW, the quoted data and the different tags are result of using _BeautifulSoup_ in the second attempt.

Comment: Answers the bonus question as well.  I was under the impression that parsed data have to be in sequence (ie i couldn't get -date, time, user- without including userID in between)

Answer (score 3):

From your description, I haven't yet figured out exactly what you are trying to do.  But I can tell you one thing right now: with regular expressions, Python raw strings are your friend.

Try using `r'pattern'` instead of just `'pattern'` in your BeautifulSoup program.

Also, when you are working with regular expressions, sometimes it is valuable to start with simple patterns, verify that they work, then build them up. You have gone straight to complicated patterns, and I'm certain they don't work since you didn't use the raw strings and the backslashes won't be right.

Comment: @chown's answer is useful (complimentary) too!

Comment: r'patern' doesn't cut it.  Same error.  The patterns work, but even if they didn't, it would return [],  not an error.

Comment: I never claimed that raw strings would solve all your problems.  But I do claim that the backslash stuff won't work the way you expect unless you use raw strings.  You either need to double every backslash, or use raw strings.

Answer (score 1):

The `.findNext()` methods will return a `BeautifulSoup.Tag` object, which cannot be passed to `re.findall`.  Therefore, you need to use `.getText()` (or a similar method to get the text from the `Tag` object.  Or `.contents` to get the html inside of that tag).  Also, when using `re.compile`, the returned object is what you need to call `findall` on.

This:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(stripped)

table = soup.find('table', width='90%')
table2 = table.findNext('table', width='90%')
table3 = table2.findNext('table', width='90%') #this is the table I need to work with

patAttackDate = re.compile('<td align="center">(\d+/\d+/\d+)<br />(\d+:\d+:\d+ \w+)')
searchAttackDate = re.findall(patAttackDate, table3)
```

Should be written like this (the last line is the only thing that needs changing):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(stripped)

table = soup.find('table', width='90%')
table2 = table.findNext('table', width='90%')
table3 = table2.findNext('table', width='90%')

patAttackDate = re.compile('<td align="center">(\d+/\d+/\d+)<br />(\d+:\d+:\d+ \w+)')
searchAttackDate = patAttackDate.findall(table3.getText())

# or, to search the html inside table3 and not just the text
# searchAttackDate = patAttackDate.findall(str(table3.contents[0]))
```

[BeautifulSoup Documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html)

From the [`re` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

> ```
> re.compile(pattern, flags=0)
> ```
>
> Compile a regular expression pattern into a **regular expression object**.
>
> This:
>   `result = re.match(pattern, string)`
>
> is equivalent to:
>   `prog = re.compile(pattern)`
>   `result = prog.match(string)`

Comment: searchAttackDate = re.findall(patAttackDate, htmlA1), works fine... I have posted 2 different attempts at solving a problem and each one uses different variables.  Looks like I need make the code separation more visible.  sorry for the mixup

Comment: @k3rb3r05 Oh, ok.  But, in the bottom part of the question, the error: `return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)  TypeError: expected string or buffer` is because you need to call `findall` like this: `patAttackDate.findall(table3)`.

Comment: Same error.  I am guessing it's the _table3_ (because it's a beautifulsoup by-product)that throws it out of whack.  If I use htmlA1, it works fine but then I won't have HTML stripped from _newline_

Comment: @k3rb3r05 Hmm, if it still gives the same `TypeError` saying it is expecting a `string or buffer`, then that means `table3` is not a string.  Might it be `None`?  You can put something like `print type(table3)` right above that call to make sure.

Comment: didn't think of that... gives me: <class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'>

Comment: @k3rb3r05 Ah! Then do `patAttackDate.findall(table3.getText())`.

Comment: Not sure it works.  Sure, it doesn't spit an error but it returns an empty string.  Take a look at **EDIT 3** at my original post.

Comment: @k3rb3r05 Sorry, I gave you the wrong method on accident.  In your edit3, change `patTest.findall(test2.getText())` to `patTest.findall(str(test2.contents[0]))`.

Comment: Your solution didn't work as intended.  Broke the regex.  But you pointed me to the right direction (hence the up-vote) . So I converted table3 to string (_strTable3 = str(table3)_) prior to applying regex on it. (edit 4 on the original post)

Answer (score 0):

for the beautifulsoup solution you can use this (without checking the regex - also I'm sure @steveha is right about addin r''):

```
searchAttackDate = table3.findAll(patAttackDate)
for row in searchAttackDate:
   print row
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: _searchAttackDate = table3.findall(patAttackDate)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable_